# Python: Compare 2 pandas dataframe with unequal number of rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Need to compare two pandas dataframe with unequal number of rows and generate a new df with True for matching records and False for non matching and missing records.

```
df1:
         date   x  y
0  2022-11-01   4  5
1  2022-11-02  12  5
2  2022-11-03  11  3


df2:
         date   x  y
0  2022-11-01   4  5
1  2022-11-02  11  5


expected df_output:
   date   x     y
0  True   True  True
1  False  False False
2  False  False False
```

Code:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2022-11-01', '2022-11-02', '2022-11-03'],'x':[4,12,11],'y':[5,5,3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2022-11-01', '2022-11-02'],'x':[4,11],'y':[5,5]})

df_output = pd.DataFrame(np.where(df1 == df2, True, False), columns=df1.columns)
print(df_output)
```

Error: `ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects`

Comment: It's unclear how you want to make the comparison. By date or by index?

Comment: I want to compare by date.

Comment: Is it expected to have False for 2022-11-02/y?

Comment: Yes. False for 2022-11-02: True  False   True  and 2022-11-03: False  False  False

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
# cell to cell equality
# comparing by date
df3 = df1.eq(df1[['date']].merge(df2, on='date', how='left'))
# or to compare by index
# df3 = df1.eq(df2, axis=1)

# if you also want to turn a row to False if there is any False
df3 = (df3.T & df3.all(axis=1)).T
```

Output:

```
    date      x      y
0   True   True   True
1  False  False  False
2  False  False  False
```

Comment: This works exactly as I wanted. Thanks